# porting cascade model from Matlab to OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, matlab-cvst, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I'm currently designing an algorithm for car detection using Matlab. In order to do so, I'm using the cascade classifier tools provided by Matlab. By the end of the process, I'll get an `xml` file which contains my classifier model. I'd like to know **if I can use this 'xml' model as is in OpenCV while porting my algorithm to `C++`?**

thanks for your help

Comment: @berak I'm using the Matlab function `trainCascadeObjectDetector` with HoG features in order to produce the xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you look at the resulting xml file, you should see a comment at the top telling you which version of OpenCV it is compatible with.